# Storing media query results via CSS for jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

There are some media queries that can't be done in JavaScript, so I've been storing them as dummy properties in CSS to detect with jQuery:

## CSS

```
#mobile-check{
  display:none;
  z-index:1;
}
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    #mobile-check {
        z-index:2;
    }
}
```

## HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="mobile-check">
        <!-- checks device-width, leave empty -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## JS

```
var mobile = false;
var check = $("#mobile-check").css("z-index");
if (check==2) { mobile = true; }
if(mobile){ [...] }
```

I was just wondering if this was considered poor practice, or if there's an established method for doing this.

Comment: why not simply do like CSS ? you test the width/height of browser to know if you are on mobile or not

Comment: use this librairie for resposive [javascript media query](http://www.responsivejs.com/demo/example1.html)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think some devices provide a higher width because of their pixel ratio, so the results can be misleading. (iPhone X has a max width of 812px, which I would prefer to use as a desktop breakpoint.)

Comment: @M0ns1f Thanks, but I'm hoping to find a work around without needing another library. This does look good though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) which you can also use within resize event if needed

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function responsiveRule(){
     if($(window).width < 400) {

     }
   }
   $(window).resize(function() {
     responsiveRule();
   });
});
```

Instead of using CSS for checking whether it is mobile screen or not; window.width() can be used.